# Error: 'the requested database is not defined in configuration'?

Tags: c#, sql, enterprise-library

i have c# app that connects with database. I am trying to make a setup of my project. What i have done is that i have added a setup project and then added my app.exe,app.config, microsoft libraries into the application folder. Build the project installed it but it gives an error "the requested database is not defined in configuration". here is the code

```
           <connectionStrings>
           <add name="chk" connectionString="server=my-
           PC;Database=cust_man;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
           <add name="cust_man.Properties.Settings.chk" connectionString="Initial 
           Catalog=cust_man;Data Source=my-PC;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
           <add name="Customer_Management.Properties.Settings.datasource" connectionString="Data
           Source=my-PC;Initial Catalog=cust_man;Integrated Security=True" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
           </connectionStrings>
```

Its the connection string that i was using before making a setup of project and it was working then i searched for the error and tried replacing my connection string with this

```
           <connectionStrings>

           <add name="cust_man" connectionString="Database=cust_man;Server= 
           (local)\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\database\cust_man.mdf;Integrated 
           Security=True;User Instance=True"

           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

           </connectionStrings>
```

but still it gives the same error and one more thing i have used enterprise library so i used this for function

```
       Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("chk");
```

Please Help as this is new for making a setup of project

Comment: The string argument to CreateDatabase must match the name of one of your connection strings so you need to put your original connection string back in the config and work from there. The app.config needs to be in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: If you add your connection string to the app.config that is in your startup project, as Rikalous suggested, it should automatically be copied to your ~\bin\Debug folder when you start debugging.

Comment: my Database name is "cust_man" did the same as you said but still the same error please see anything wrong in the above second connection string?

Comment: The database name doesn't matter, it's the value in the 'name' attribute that CreateDatabase is looking for.

Comment: I'm using enterprise library with it. Is this a issue with dll files?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this connection string in your app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DSN" connectionString="Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=cust_man;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then this is how you would actually use the connection string:

```
    public static DbProviderFactory Factory
    {
        get
        {
            if (dbProviderFactoryEmployee == null)
            {
                ConnectionStringSettings connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSN"];
                dbProviderFactoryEmployee = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionSettings.ProviderName);
                ConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;
            }
            return dbProviderFactoryEmployee;
        }
    }

    private static SqlConnection GetDbConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        dbConnection.Open();
        return dbConnection;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you are using LINQ to SQL, doesn't it give you a server explorer where you can drag and drop items onto your DBML file?  See this image:

[image]

The designer should then automatically put your connection string into the project's app.config file.  You just have to copy that connection string over to your UI project's app.config.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you are having problems with the setup program in deploying your application to other computers, then you need to change your connection string from localhost:

```
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
```

To always point to the database server:

```
MyDatabaseServer\SQLEXPRESS
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Is your SQL Server firewall port number open on your database server?  You can also take a look at these articles to help you see if you have missed something important:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215712/LINQ-to-SQL-Basic-Concepts-and-Features
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136028/Learn-SQL-to-LINQ-Visual-Representation

Comment: still getting the same error ......and this is how i am using the connection string                                             public int checkplatenum(string platenum)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar("checkplatenum", new object[] { platenum }));
        }

Comment: So are you using LINQ to SQL?  Is the db from your db.ExecuteScalar a data context?  You should be using your connection string earlier on before actually executing a database command.

Comment: Yeah i'm using linq to sql. Look roger everything is working fine in my project getting and storing data in database. But its just causing an issue when try to make a setup project

Comment: So it just doesn't work when you use your setup project to install the application on a different computer?

Comment: Did it help to change your connection string in my UPDATE 2 above?

Comment: i have windows authentication turned on for sql server ?

Comment: I think that is your problem--change it to sql server authentication if you are going to be making these calls from different computers.

Comment: while making setup project we actually connect database.mdf file and make a connection for that right? So do you think that windows authentication would be doing any problem there ? @roger

Comment: Would you be able to upload the code somewhere so I could take a look at it?